# Do I have to create my own model to be able to write in the password_resets table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my app, a new user can be created without specifying a password. I want to send that user an email with a Set Password link (including a token), exactly like the Reset Password email.

To use and write a token to the password_resets table, do I have to create a password_reset model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import DB class and then you can use DB class; somethings like this:

```
DB::table('reset_passwords')->action()->get();
```

without need to create a model.